# How to override Structuremap registry in integration tests for Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap

I am writting UI Integration tests/Acceptance tests for a MVC website. I want to be able to override the repository classes at run time for these tests with my InMemory repository classes.

I am using Structuremap default configuration and the thing that I want to achieve is to tell my acceptance tests to use InMemory Repositories instead of the default ones that are configured.

I am not sure how this can be done? Can you please guide me?

I am not interested in using In Memory DBs or No SQL DBs for this purpose so kindly advice me how can I change the class instance at run time.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation gives some examples of how to do this.

http://docs.structuremap.net/ChangingConfigurationAtRuntime.htm